# BIRT XML missing rows

Tags: xml, xpath, birt, columnmappings

I'm using an XML file for a Data Source that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Sats xmlns="http://nus/data">
  <Sat SatNum="14084">
    <SatName Priority="1">
      <SaName>93</SaName>
      <SaNameClass ComID="1">
        <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
      </SaNameClass>
    </SatName>
    <SatStat ComID="3">
      <SatStatName>act</SatStatName>
    </SatStat>
    <Mis>MI</Mis>
    <SubSys ComID="-2">
      <SubSysStat ComID="1">
        <SatSubSysStat>act</SatSubSysStat>
      </SubSysStat>
      <SubSysName>Gen161</SubSysName>
      <SubSysDesc>Gen</SubSysDesc>
      <SubSysGp ComID="1">
        <SatSubSysGpName>Default</SatSubSysGpName>
      </SubSysGp>
      <SubSysType ComID="2">
        <SatSubSysTypeName>optical</SatSubSysTypeName>
      </SubSysType>
      <LEff ComID="23">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="8">
          <WaLenName>0.53</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>0</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>0</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>0</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="3">
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffComments>ch 1</LEffComments>
        <LEffClass ComID="1">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="274">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="4">
          <WaLenName>0.63</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>0</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>0</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>0</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="3">
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffComments>L ch 1</LEffComments>
        <LEffClass ComID="1">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="118">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="3">
          <WaLenName>1.06</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>0</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>0</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>0</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="3">
          <LEffTypeName>age</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffComments>L ch 1</LEffComments>
        <LEffClass ComID="1">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="-118">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="2">
          <WaLenName>1.3</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>0</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>0</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>0</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="3">
          <LEffTypeName>age</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffComments>L ch 1</LEffComments>
        <LEffClass ComID="1">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="191">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="10">
          <WaLenName>1.55</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>0</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>0</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>0</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="3">
          <LEffTypeName>Lotsa Damage</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffComments>L ch 1</LEffComments>
        <LEffClass ComID="1">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="1057">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="1">
          <WaLenName>3.8</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>0</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>0</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>0</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="3">
          <LEffTypeName>l age</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffComments>L ch 1</LEffComments>
        <LEffClass ComID="1">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="346">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="5">
          <WaLenName>10.6</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>0</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>0</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>0</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="3">
          <LEffTypeName>l age</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffComments>L ch 1</LEffComments>
        <LEffClass ComID="1">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <SubSysClass ComID="1">
        <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
      </SubSysClass>
      <SatSubSysAssocClass ComID="1">
        <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
      </SatSubSysAssocClass>
    </SubSys>
    <SubSys ComID="-89">
      <SubSysStat ComID="1">
        <SatSubSysStat>act</SatSubSysStat>
      </SubSysStat>
      <SubSysName>Op201</SubSysName>
      <SubSysDesc>Auto Gen</SubSysDesc>
      <SubSysGp ComID="1">
        <SatSubSysGpName>Default</SatSubSysGpName>
      </SubSysGp>
      <SubSysType ComID="3">
        <SatSubSysTypeName>opti</SatSubSysTypeName>
      </SubSysType>
      <LEff ComID="348">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="8">
          <WaLenName>0.53</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>6</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>16</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>15</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="1">
          <LEffTypeName>Sure</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeComments>No age</LEffTypeComments>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffClass ComID="0">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="12">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="4">
          <WaLenName>0.63</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>17</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>1</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>8</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="1">
          <LEffTypeName>Sure</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeComments>No age </LEffTypeComments>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffClass ComID="0">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="-159">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="3">
          <WaLenName>1.06</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>19</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>101</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>133</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="1">
          <LEffTypeName>Sure</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeComments>age </LEffTypeComments>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffClass ComID="0">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="-1486759460">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="2">
          <WaLenName>1.3</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>13</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>7</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>11</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="1">
          <LEffTypeName>Sure</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeComments>No age</LEffTypeComments>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffClass ComID="0">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="86">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="10">
          <WaLenName>1.55</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>1</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>1</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>29</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="1">
          <LEffTypeName>sure</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeComments>no age</LEffTypeComments>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffClass ComID="0">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="116">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="1">
          <WaLenName>3.8</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>94</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>5</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>1</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="1">
          <LEffTypeName>sure</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeComments>no age</LEffTypeComments>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffClass ComID="0">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="144">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="5">
          <WaLenName>10.6</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>9</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>1</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>75</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="1">
          <LEffTypeName>sure</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeComments>no age</LEffTypeComments>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffClass ComID="0">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <SubSysClass ComID="1">
        <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
      </SubSysClass>
      <SatSubSysAssocClass ComID="1">
        <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
      </SatSubSysAssocClass>
    </SubSys>
    <SatClass ComID="1">
      <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
    </SatClass>
  </Sat>
  <Sat SatNum="10101010">
    <SatName Priority="1">
      <SaName>112293</SaName>
      <SaNameClass ComID="1">
        <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
      </SaNameClass>
    </SatName>
        <SatName Priority="1">
      <SaName>321393</SaName>
      <SaNameClass ComID="1">
        <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
      </SaNameClass>
    </SatName>
        <SatName Priority="1">
      <SaName>2315668435393</SaName>
      <SaNameClass ComID="1">
        <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
      </SaNameClass>
    </SatName>
    <SatStat ComID="3">
      <SatStatName>act</SatStatName>
    </SatStat>
    <Mis>MI</Mis>
    <SubSys ComID="-2">
      <SubSysStat ComID="1">
        <SatSubSysStat>act</SatSubSysStat>
      </SubSysStat>
      <SubSysName>Gen161</SubSysName>
      <SubSysDesc>Gen</SubSysDesc>
      <SubSysGp ComID="1">
        <SatSubSysGpName>Default</SatSubSysGpName>
      </SubSysGp>
      <SubSysType ComID="2">
        <SatSubSysTypeName>optical</SatSubSysTypeName>
      </SubSysType>
      <LEff ComID="23">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="8">
          <WaLenName>0.53</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>0</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>0</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>0</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="3">
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffComments>ch 1</LEffComments>
        <LEffClass ComID="1">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="274">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="4">
          <WaLenName>0.63</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>0</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>0</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>0</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="3">
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffComments>L ch 1</LEffComments>
        <LEffClass ComID="1">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="118">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="3">
          <WaLenName>1.06</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>0</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>0</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>0</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="3">
          <LEffTypeName>age</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffComments>L ch 1</LEffComments>
        <LEffClass ComID="1">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="-118">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="2">
          <WaLenName>1.3</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>0</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>0</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>0</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="3">
          <LEffTypeName>age</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffComments>L ch 1</LEffComments>
        <LEffClass ComID="1">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="191">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="10">
          <WaLenName>1.55</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>0</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>0</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>0</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="3">
          <LEffTypeName>Lotsa Damage</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffComments>L ch 1</LEffComments>
        <LEffClass ComID="1">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="1057">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="1">
          <WaLenName>3.8</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>0</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>0</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>0</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="3">
          <LEffTypeName>l age</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffComments>L ch 1</LEffComments>
        <LEffClass ComID="1">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="346">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="5">
          <WaLenName>10.6</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>0</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>0</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>0</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="3">
          <LEffTypeName>l age</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffComments>L ch 1</LEffComments>
        <LEffClass ComID="1">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <SubSysClass ComID="1">
        <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
      </SubSysClass>
      <SatSubSysAssocClass ComID="1">
        <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
      </SatSubSysAssocClass>
    </SubSys>
    <SubSys ComID="-89">
      <SubSysStat ComID="1">
        <SatSubSysStat>act</SatSubSysStat>
      </SubSysStat>
      <SubSysName>Op201</SubSysName>
      <SubSysDesc>Auto Gen</SubSysDesc>
      <SubSysGp ComID="1">
        <SatSubSysGpName>Default</SatSubSysGpName>
      </SubSysGp>
      <SubSysType ComID="3">
        <SatSubSysTypeName>opti</SatSubSysTypeName>
      </SubSysType>
      <LEff ComID="348">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="8">
          <WaLenName>0.53</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>6</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>16</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>15</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="1">
          <LEffTypeName>Sure</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeComments>No age</LEffTypeComments>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffClass ComID="0">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="12">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="4">
          <WaLenName>0.63</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>17</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>1</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>8</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="1">
          <LEffTypeName>Sure</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeComments>No age </LEffTypeComments>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffClass ComID="0">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="-159">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="3">
          <WaLenName>1.06</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>19</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>101</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>133</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="1">
          <LEffTypeName>Sure</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeComments>age </LEffTypeComments>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffClass ComID="0">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="-1486759460">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="2">
          <WaLenName>1.3</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>13</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>7</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>11</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="1">
          <LEffTypeName>Sure</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeComments>No age</LEffTypeComments>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffClass ComID="0">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="86">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="10">
          <WaLenName>1.55</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>1</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>1</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>29</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="1">
          <LEffTypeName>sure</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeComments>no age</LEffTypeComments>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffClass ComID="0">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="116">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="1">
          <WaLenName>3.8</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>94</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>5</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>1</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="1">
          <LEffTypeName>sure</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeComments>no age</LEffTypeComments>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffClass ComID="0">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <LEff ComID="144">
        <LEffWaLen ComID="5">
          <WaLenName>10.6</WaLenName>
        </LEffWaLen>
        <ExageCWI>9</ExageCWI>
        <ExageCWF>1</ExageCWF>
        <ExagePF>75</ExagePF>
        <EffT ComID="1">
          <LEffTypeName>sure</LEffTypeName>
          <LEffTypeComments>no age</LEffTypeComments>
          <LEffTypeClass ComID="1">
            <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
          </LEffTypeClass>
        </EffT>
        <LEffClass ComID="0">
          <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
        </LEffClass>
      </LEff>
      <SubSysClass ComID="1">
        <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
      </SubSysClass>
      <SatSubSysAssocClass ComID="1">
        <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
      </SatSubSysAssocClass>
    </SubSys>
    <SatClass ComID="1">
      <ClassLong>un</ClassLong>
    </SatClass>
  </Sat>
</Sats>
```

My row mapping is `/Sats/Sat/SubSys/LEff`
And my Column mapping is

SatNum = `../../@SatNum`

SaName = `../../SatName/SaName`

ExageCWI = `ExageCWI`

SubSysName = `../SubSysName`

Everything is returning a value but the SaName is missing records. It is only retrieving the first record of SaName.

```
SatNum   SaName   ExageCWI   SubSysName   
14084    93       0          Gen161
14084    93       0          Gen161
14084    93       0          Gen161
14084    93       0          Gen161
14084    93       0          Gen161
14084    93       0          Gen161
14084    93       0          Gen161
14084    93       6          Op201
14084    93       17         Op201
14084    93       19         Op201
14084    93       13         Op201
14084    93       1          Op201
14084    93       94         Op201
14084    93       9          Op201
10101010 112293   0          Gen161
10101010 112293   0          Gen161
10101010 112293   0          Gen161
10101010 112293   0          Gen161
10101010 112293   0          Gen161
10101010 112293   0          Gen161
10101010 112293   0          Gen161
10101010 112293   0          Gen161
10101010 112293   6          Op201 
10101010 112293   17         Op201
10101010 112293   19         Op201
10101010 112293   13         Op201
10101010 112293   1          Op201
10101010 112293   94         Op201
10101010 112293   9          Op201
```

I'm expecting to see SaName `2315668435393` and `321393` in there.
Thanks for the help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.23" id="1">
    <property name="createdBy">Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 4.6.0.v201606072122</property>
    <property name="units">in</property>
    <property name="iconFile">/templates/blank_report.gif</property>
    <property name="bidiLayoutOrientation">ltr</property>
    <property name="imageDPI">120</property>
    <data-sources>
        <oda-data-source extensionID="org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml" name="Data Source" id="7">
            <property name="FILELIST">C:\Users\1122335\Desktop\14084.xml</property>
        </oda-data-source>
    </data-sources>
    <data-sets>
        <oda-data-set extensionID="org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.dataSet" name="Data Set" id="8">
            <list-property name="columnHints">
                <structure>
                    <property name="columnName">SatNum</property>
                    <property name="analysis">dimension</property>
                    <text-property name="heading">SatNum</text-property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="columnName">SaName</property>
                    <property name="analysis">dimension</property>
                    <text-property name="heading">SaName</text-property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="columnName">ExageCWI</property>
                    <property name="analysis">dimension</property>
                    <text-property name="heading">ExageCWI</text-property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="columnName">SubSysName</property>
                    <property name="analysis">dimension</property>
                    <text-property name="heading">SubSysName</text-property>
                </structure>
            </list-property>
            <list-property name="parameters"/>
            <structure name="cachedMetaData">
                <list-property name="resultSet">
                    <structure>
                        <property name="position">1</property>
                        <property name="name">SatNum</property>
                        <property name="dataType">string</property>
                    </structure>
                    <structure>
                        <property name="position">2</property>
                        <property name="name">SaName</property>
                        <property name="dataType">string</property>
                    </structure>
                    <structure>
                        <property name="position">3</property>
                        <property name="name">ExageCWI</property>
                        <property name="dataType">string</property>
                    </structure>
                    <structure>
                        <property name="position">4</property>
                        <property name="name">SubSysName</property>
                        <property name="dataType">string</property>
                    </structure>
                </list-property>
            </structure>
            <property name="dataSource">Data Source</property>
            <list-property name="resultSet">
                <structure>
                    <property name="position">1</property>
                    <property name="name">SatNum</property>
                    <property name="nativeName">SatNum</property>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                    <property name="nativeDataType">12</property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="position">2</property>
                    <property name="name">SaName</property>
                    <property name="nativeName">SaName</property>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                    <property name="nativeDataType">12</property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="position">3</property>
                    <property name="name">ExageCWI</property>
                    <property name="nativeName">ExageCWI</property>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                    <property name="nativeDataType">12</property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="position">4</property>
                    <property name="name">SubSysName</property>
                    <property name="nativeName">SubSysName</property>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                    <property name="nativeDataType">12</property>
                </structure>
            </list-property>
            <xml-property name="queryText"><![CDATA[table0#-TNAME-#table0#:#[/Sats/Sat/SubSys/LEff]#:#{SatNum;STRING;../../@SatNum},{SaName;STRING;../../SatName/SaName},{ExageCWI;STRING;/ExageCWI},{SubSysName;STRING;../SubSysName}#:#<"","http:%%nus%data">]]></xml-property>
            <xml-property name="designerValues"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<model:DesignValues xmlns:design="http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/connectivity/oda/design" xmlns:model="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/report/model/adapter/odaModel">
  <Version>2.0</Version>
  <design:ResultSets derivedMetaData="true">
    <design:resultSetDefinitions>
      <design:resultSetColumns>
        <design:resultColumnDefinitions>
          <design:attributes>
            <design:identifier>
              <design:name>SatNum</design:name>
              <design:position>1</design:position>
            </design:identifier>
            <design:nativeDataTypeCode>12</design:nativeDataTypeCode>
            <design:precision>-1</design:precision>
            <design:scale>-1</design:scale>
            <design:nullability>Unknown</design:nullability>
          </design:attributes>
          <design:usageHints>
            <design:label>SatNum</design:label>
            <design:formattingHints/>
          </design:usageHints>
        </design:resultColumnDefinitions>
        <design:resultColumnDefinitions>
          <design:attributes>
            <design:identifier>
              <design:name>SatName</design:name>
              <design:position>2</design:position>
            </design:identifier>
            <design:nativeDataTypeCode>12</design:nativeDataTypeCode>
            <design:precision>-1</design:precision>
            <design:scale>-1</design:scale>
            <design:nullability>Unknown</design:nullability>
          </design:attributes>
          <design:usageHints>
            <design:label>SatName</design:label>
            <design:formattingHints/>
          </design:usageHints>
        </design:resultColumnDefinitions>
      </design:resultSetColumns>
      <design:criteria/>
    </design:resultSetDefinitions>
  </design:ResultSets>
</model:DesignValues>]]></xml-property>
            <list-property name="privateDriverProperties">
                <ex-property>
                    <name>MAX_ROW</name>
                    <value>-1</value>
                </ex-property>
                <ex-property>
                    <name>XML_FILE</name>
                </ex-property>
            </list-property>
        </oda-data-set>
    </data-sets>
    <page-setup>
        <simple-master-page name="Simple MasterPage" id="2">
            <page-footer>
                <text id="3">
                    <property name="contentType">html</property>
                    <text-property name="content"><![CDATA[<value-of>new Date()</value-of>]]></text-property>
                </text>
            </page-footer>
        </simple-master-page>
    </page-setup>
</report>
```

Here is the BIRT XML Source if that helps

Comment: Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @GillesQuenot What else would you like to see?

Comment: 'How to create a **Minimal**, Reproducible Example'. Not the case here

Comment: @GillesQuenot I'm not sure what you mean, I believe this is a Reproducible Example